# jQuery -> image jumping over the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code and i want that code to switch between bulletproof armor vests. When switching from the first to the second, nothing wrong will happen, but switching to the first creates a strange effect. How can i solve this?

http://www.bykwien.nl/soldier2/voorbeeld.html

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4R3TS/

```
$('#vest1').click(function(){
            $('.block1').fadeIn();
            $('.block2').fadeOut();
            $('.vest').addClass('hide');
            $('.vest1').removeClass('hide');
            $('.vest1').css({
                position: 'relative',
                top: '-105px',
                left: '12px',
            });
        });

        $('#vest2').click(function(){
            $('.block1, .block2').fadeIn();
            $('.vest').addClass('hide');
            $('.vest2').removeClass('hide');
            $('.vest2').css({
                position: 'relative',
                top: '-210px',
                left: '12px',
            });
        });
```

Comment: Instead of `position:relative;` you should be able to use `position:absolute` and that should stop the images jumping when you change them - http://jsfiddle.net/4R3TS/1/

Comment: Actually you need rework this html for right position. But you can use absolute position for block2: http://jsfiddle.net/4R3TS/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as Nick said in the comments, or change from

```
fadeIn()
fadeOut()
```

to

```
show()
hide()
```

It happens on the first one because when you click for `#vest2`, you `hide` then both then `unhide` `#vest2`, so `#vest1` dissapears instantly.

But when going back to `#vest1`, you don't instantly hide them and both of them are on-screen for a split second while one is fading out and one is fading it, resulting in that 'jump' you get.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/4R3TS/4/)

Comment: I gave the parent a position absolute, so the images stays in that box. They still keep jumping over. Also changed from fadeIn and Out to Show() hide() but still the same issue

Comment: I added a link @DonnyvanV